# Использование scipy.optimize

Tags: python, scipy

Нужно минимизировать функцию, зависящую от двух переменных, используя алгоритм *Нелдера-Мида*. В документации сказано ([ссылка](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-neldermead.html#optimize-minimize-neldermead)), что в `options` у данной функции можно указать `xtol`, но при этом оно принимается как `float`.
Как указать `xtol` для каждой из двух варьируемых переменных, притом, что они имеют разный порядок? Пробовал запись вида `'xtol':[1,0.01]` - ругается.
Код:

```
import Residual_calc as res_c
from scipy.optimize import minimize

var_ar0=[25,1.0];

var_ar_min=minimize(res_c.x_extr_res,var_ar0,(),'Nelder-Mead',options={'disp':True,'maxiter':10});
```

Comment: В коде функции 'Nelder-Mead' не предусмотрено использование нескольких значений для 'xtol'. Как вариант, написать свою функцию для минимизации. Взять код из функции scipy.optimize.optimize._minimize_neldermead и добавить проверку на несколько значений xtol.

Answer (score 1):

Если переменные имеют разный порядок, надо сделать линейную замену переменных, чтобы порядок был тем же. Тогда одного значения xtol хватит, и заодно, вероятно, улучшится производительность метода.

Привожу пример такой замены. У функции f переменные разного порядка; и этот дефект функция scaledf исправляет.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def f(x):
    return 3**(x[0]**2) + 3**(1e-8*x[1]**2)

def scaledf(x):
    return f([x[0], 1e4*x[1]])

res = minimize(f, [1,1], method='Nelder-Mead', options={'xtol': 1e-6})
print(res)
res2 = minimize(scaledf, [1,1], method='Nelder-Mead', options={'xtol': 1e-6})
print(res2)
```

Сравнение результатов (настоящий минимум в (0,0)):

```
[ 8.64722640e-09,   1.65971984e-04]   для f
[-3.37014990e-07,  -8.87487948e-08]   для scaledf
```

---

Заодно замечу, что происходит, если не устанавливать опции:

```
res = minimize(f, [1,1])
print(res)
res2 = minimize(scaledf, [1,1])
print(res2)
```

Результат для f никуда не годится;  для scaledf вполне приемлемый.

```
[-1.10723146e-07,   9.99999971e-01]   для f
[-1.13095095e-07,  -1.13095095e-07]   для scaledf
```